# Ext JS - Combine 2 jsons from 2 endpoints into one Store

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have 2 endpoints, and each of them returns a JSON (actually 3 but let's make it simple). I can't combine them on the server side because I don't have access to it.

I need to display the data in an Ext.grid.Panel which accepts only one Store object. I tried making a model for each JSON and then somehow combining them, but I failed. So I'm thinking of joining them with a where clause, and I need to match the id from one JSON to bar_id from another JSON. For example like this:

```
{ "success": true,
  "total": 3,
  "message": "Data loaded",
  "data": [
            {"id": "1", "object_name": "foo1", "bar_id": 1},
            {"id": "2", "object_name": "foo2", "bar_id": 2},
            {"id": "3", "object_name": "foo3", "bar_id": 3}
          ]
}
```

And the other one:

```
{ "success": true,
  "total": 5,
  "message": "Data loaded",
  "data": [
            {"id": "1", "bar_name": "bar1"},
            {"id": "2", "bar_name": "bar2"},
            {"id": "3", "bar_name": "bar3"}
          ]
}
```

And I want to combine them like this:

```
[
  {"id": "1", "object_name": "foo1", "bar_id": 1, "bar_name": "bar1"},
  {"id": "2", "object_name": "foo2", "bar_id": 2, "bar_name": "bar2"},
  {"id": "3", "object_name": "foo3", "bar_id": 3, "bar_name": "bar3"}
]
```

So I need something like: where FirstModel.bar_id equals SecondModel.id. Then I need to make a Store from this JSON. As you can see, I'm just starting with Ext JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cao Urose,

Use one model based on combining your two response data arrays. Combining your two arrays is more a js issue than it is extjs issue. When you join your two data arrays, it will be straightforward to create a model and load your store.

Comment: Ćao, so should I make a function to do this or is there some function that could do the job for me? I'll just google it anyway, thanks.